# SIMD extensions on power: compiler flags and processor support

Tags: simd, powerpc, altivec

I am looking into porting a generic library of abstractions on top of SIMD to power architecture.

However, the information about which extensions are supported on which power and how to compile to them is confusing. At the moment only looking at 64 bit processors and no older than power-7.

On one hand I see this [document](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.aix.doc/compiler_ref/vec_cmpgt.html).

There are 3 types of instructions: no requirements, requires power-8 and requires power-9.

For example `vec_cmpgt` has no special requirements.

However, when I use `powerpc64-linux-gnu-g++-10` I see an error:

```
error: '__builtin_altivec_vcmpgtsd' requires the '-mpower8-vector' option
```

In some other places I can find information about `vmx` and `vsx` extensions but it is also unclear to which power iterations the correspond to.
For example [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGH4D_15.1.2/com.ibm.xlf151.aix.doc/getstart/architecture.html) it talks about vsx on power-7.

**UPD**: I missed that 64 bit integer comparison is only available on power8, but others are before that.

Comment: You might want to take a look at these two projects on github: https://github.com/ermig1979/Simd and https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde - they are both cross-platform SIMD and support PowerPC/POWER.

Comment: Are you looking for C intrinsics, or are you OK with using assembly instructions directly? If you are using C intrinsics, the behaviour may differ between compilers: your first reference points at the XL C/C++ compiler docs, but your error message is from g++.

Comment: @dja - I think that gcc is the only viable option for me since the library I am look to port is C++20. But that's a good reference point, thanks.

Comment: You might also be interested in the powerpc compatibility shim for intel intrinsics: see e.g. https://www.talospace.com/2019/07/easier-power-vectorizing-for-fun-and.html - in short, you can probably do a lot with just `-DNO_WARN_X86_INTRINSICS` and treating ppc like x86.

Comment: @dja - they are emulated, right? still interesting

Comment: Not really, they're translated at compile time. So you write your usual x86 C intrinsic code, include the header, and get ppc64 vector operations in your program. Check out for example `_mm_min_ps` and following in https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/rs6000/xmmintrin.h#L458: you get a `vec_cmpgt` and a `vec_sel`, which works out to be 2 vector instructions: https://godbolt.org/z/o6s1je

Comment: @dja that's what I mean by emulated. The whole point of the library is to have the most efficient abstractions for cross platform SIMD and the x86 way is not the most efficient way for power.

Comment: well, sometimes it will map 1-to-1, or the compiler will optimise it to be efficient, sometimes it won't. If you want to build up optimal higher-level operations from scratch, you're going to need to spend a lot of time in the weeds of each targeted compiler's vector intrinsics (e.g. focus just on gcc, excluding AIX XL C docs), and/or spend some quality time with the ISA and a powerpc assembler. I'll post some links as an answer.

Comment: @dja can you also add what is vmx and vsx please? I find those confusing.

Comment: I've added a link in my answer to  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086151/463510 which will hopefully explain it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few resources that will help you on your quest.

Firstly, the actual underlying vector instructions in the CPU which are available to you vary by CPU version. These are documented in the ISA. For:

- Power7, this is the [Power ISA v2.06](http://kib.kiev.ua/x86docs/POWER/PowerISA_V2.06B_V2_PUBLIC.pdf) (pdf)
- Power8, this is the [Power ISA v2.07](https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=ibm-power-isa-version-2-07-b)
- Power9, this is the [Power ISA v3.0](https://openpowerfoundation.org/?resource_lib=power-isa-version-3-0)

These are all massive PDFs telling you many things, including the details of the vector instructions. You can use these directly if you write your code in assembler.

Then, you have noticed that the supported compiler intrinsics can vary from compiler to compiler: you picked up a reference from the very-google-friendly AIX XL C compiler manual, and found it didn't work on gcc.

So you'd want to spend some quality time with:

- the gcc manual page on [vector extensions generally](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html)
- the page on [PowerPC vector builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/PowerPC-AltiVec_002fVSX-Built-in-Functions.html#PowerPC-AltiVec_002fVSX-Built-in-Functions) - which is helpfully broken out into subpages for <= 2.05, 2.06, 2.07 and 3.0.

Power has the additional complexity of supporting different types of vector extensions with lots of different names. There's a good explainer at
[VSX? VMX? Altivec? VR? VSR?! How these PowerPC SIMD acronyms relate to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086151/463510)